# How to get total delay from two columns group by day?

Tags: mysql, delay

I have a table in a MySql database named as internet with 3 columns: id, dropped_at and dropped_to as shown in this image

[image]

> How to find total delay group by date?

Well, I have tried but it's not working properly
here is my MySql code:

```
SELECT
    dropped_at,
    dropped_to,
    TIMEDIFF(dropped_to,dropped_at) AS delay
FROM
    internet
WHERE
    WEEKDAY(dropped_at) BETWEEN 0 AND 6 AND 
  WEEK (dropped_at) = WEEK (NOW())
GROUP BY CAST(dropped_to AS DATE)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show that you tried something at least and feel free to share. **Hint:** `SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,dropped_at,dropped_to)) & GROUP BY DATE(dropped_at)`

Comment: Please provide create table and insert table query that u want help on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want total delay for each day then the following query would work:

```
SELECT 
 DATE(dropped_at) AS date,
 SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,dropped_at,dropped_to)) AS delayInMinutes
FROM internet
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date;
```

**Note:** The delay is in `MINUTES`. You can change it to any unit as you like

---

If you want the delay in **`hh:mm:ss`** format then try the following query instead

```
SELECT 
 DATE(dropped_at) AS date,
 SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,dropped_at,dropped_to))) AS delay
FROM internet
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date;
```